# File doesn't read after creating jar using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i have a small application which checks for values from a file and display the result in a jframe.

A file contain list of word to check. this file is placed in project folder "testing" and the  main source testing.java file is present in location "testing\src\testing"

```
input file : c:\document..\netbeans\testing\
java file : c:\document..\netbeans\testing\src\testing\


when i place the input file inside folder "c:\document..\netbeans\testing\src\testing\
" the input file is not taken as input, it works only when kept on folder "c:\document..\netbeans\testing\"
```

so when a jar file is created it has not included the input file in that, even i manually input that is not taking the input file in and working.

some path setting issue? what can be done to solve this issue?

any help pls??

Comment: The file is not being added to the jar? Or your program isn't reading the file?

Comment: @peeskillet file is not added to jar. need to add input.txt into jar and it should work. any sugg pls

Comment: Did you open the jar to see? Or are you just getting a `FileNotFoundException` and assuming it's not being added?

Comment: @peeskillet i have opened the jar file and seen

Comment: I not about why it's not being added, but I _can_ tell you why it's not reading when you manually add it. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: @peeskillet thanks, will check your solution and see if it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the jar, the file becomes an embedded resource. If you try to read it as a `File` it will no long be the same file system path as you originally use in the program. It must now be read from the class path.

To read the file from the class path, you will want to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`, which return an `InputStream`. If your file is in the same location (package) as your class file, then you should use

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("input.txt");
```

Then you can read from the `InputStream`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens, when you don't use absolute path...!
As when you run your program from IDE(Netbeans) then the HOME_FOLDER is your ProjectFolder. Relative to which you would have given the file_path(that has to be accessed in your program).

But after building, jar is present in ProjectFolder/dist. When you run the jar file the HomeFolder is not ProjectFolder rather it is ProjectFolder/dist.

So, to make it successful, to need to copy all files and folders from ProjectFolder/dist to ProjectFolder.

Then run the jar.. Hope it will fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

Try putting double backslashes in your file paths. Like this:

```
c:\\document..\\netbeans\\testing\\src\\testing\\
```

This is the format that java normally requires it to be in

Comment: no i dont want to put full path. currently i am using like new FileReader("input.txt") without full path, it is working, for this to work the input.txt should be in input file path as mentioned above. while building this file is not included in jar file, how to include it is my question?

Comment: So your application is names "testing" and you would like the file to appear in "testing\src\testing"?

Comment: yes. i have placed the file in that src\testing\ location, then it is not working. the program works only when the file is placed in \testing\ folder